# finding out numbers in rows and columns

Tags: permutations

[image]

- If $2731$ has to appear in $x$, we should have $910$ in $V$
- If $2731$ has to appear in $y$, we should have $546$ in $V$
- If $2731$ has to appear in $z$, we should have $390$ in $V$

I am stuck with this.  How to find out whether $910,546,390$ are not appearing in any of the columns in $w,x,y,z$??

Comment: This is from Problem #25 in [this contest](http://cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2015/2015PascalContest.pdf).

Comment: I'm not sure you asked the question you meant to.  First you give conditions for $2731$ to appear in column X,Y,Z (column W might have been an oversight) based on contents of $V$, but then you ask "to find out whether 910,546,390" do not appear in $W,X,Y,Z$.  This seems a non sequitur.

Comment: @hardmath 910 appears in $V$ iff $3\times 910+1=2731$ appears in $X$. The problem is to find which columns $2731$ appears in - so these equivalences reduce the size of the problem.

Comment: @hardmath The contest was Feb 2015

Answer (score 1):

Here is a helping hand. Working with $Z$ we have $$2731\in W \iff 390 \in V$$

Now this will happen iff $390$ doesn't appear earlier in the table. $390 =389+1$ and $389$ is not divisible by $2,3,5,7$ so it can't appear earlier.

We also have $$2731\in X \iff 910\in V$$

Now $910=909+1$ and $909$ is divisible by $3$ but not $2,5,7$. If $303\in V$ then $910$ is excluded. So $$910\in V \iff 303\notin V$$

And work systematically back to reduce the numbers involved. For example, if $303$ is excluded, where will it appear in the table?